# Good way to get HDD in a large logical disk. *7 Discs of different sizes

Tags: linux, raid, network-attached-storage, storage

Basically I would like to have one large logical disk.

Data security is important, but not critially. Typically I would like something like
1st prize: Raid 5
2nd prize: Loosing all data on failed disk, but not on any other disks.

I can run this setup on a computer on its on Linux/Windows or on a Windows machine.
I have the following drive sizes

2000 GB
1000 GB
1000 GB
750 GB
500 GB
640 GB
640 GB
250 GB

What you guys suggest?

I will be storing media on these, large HD movies, performance is not critical, but appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's the client OS/application?

Comment: I would suggest you don't bother a professional admin forum with off topic questions. Your home setup of random old discs you pulled out of somewhere does not really belong here. And no, noone will believe this is a "Professional capacity" setup. Not when you talk of "media, large HD movies". Man, the 250gb disc is not only old, it also is slow, most likely.

Comment: RAID0. Over all disks. >:D

Comment: @tombull89 I was going to suggest just LVMing the lot :)

Comment: My suggestion is throgin them away and replacing them with 80 x 1200gb HGST SAS discs ;)

Comment: Why do people ask for this so often? Why would you want so many dissimilar drives in one array?

Answer (score 2):

Just use Storage Spaces in Windows 8, and read our FAQ before posting again as you clearly haven't.